# When is $f (n) = \Omega(f (n))$

Tags: notation, algorithms, asymptotics

I know that: 
$f(n) = \Omega(f(n))$ means  $f(n) \geq c  f(n)$ 
 and that would be true only if $0 < c \leq 1.$

So what would be a formal definition for $f(n) = \Omega(f(n))?$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is wrong with $0<c\leq 1?$ It doesn't have to be true for all $c.$

Comment: I was not sure if only that condition would qualify  as a formal definition. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: There is some variation regarding the defiitions of the various notations of the big-O family between different authors. Usually, all variations agree at least when $f$ is positive (some authors use fewer absolute-vaue-bars, or use the quotient of the functrions in the definition; hence the problems when functions can be negative or zero). However, specifically for $\Omega$, there is the additional distinction Hardy-Littlewood vs. Knuth. Nevertheless, $f(n)=\Omega(f(n))$ holds true for both variants (again, at least when $f$ is positive)

Comment: To correct the statement, if $f$ is positive, then $f(n) = \Omega(f(n))$ means: *there exists* $c > 0$ and *there exists* $n_0$ such that *for all* $n$, if $n \ge n_0$ then $f(n) \ge c f(n)$.  So, the question becomes (in large part): does there *exist* a $c$ such that $0 < c \le 1$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler The definition with $n_0$ in the definition and the definition without are equivalent, at least for $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ with $f,g$ positive. You can just take $c_1=\min(c,f(1)/g(1),f(2)/g(2),\dots,f(n_0-1)/g(n_0-1)).$ Indeed, you can go further and allow $g$ to be non-negative. The only real problem leaving out $n_0$ from the definition is when $f(n)=0$ for some $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews OK, fair enough.  The $n_0$ part wasn't my focus anyway.  (The major point I was trying to make was: according to the definition, you're not asking whether the statement is true *for all* $c$, or whether the statement is true *for some previously fixed* $c$, but whether the statement is true *for some* $c$.)